# how to display wallpaper in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, wallpaper

I'm doing a leisure time iPhone game. I want to use the current wallpaper as my game background. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no API that enables you to get the current wallpaper.